# Javascript - Singleton - Race Condition

Tags: javascript, singleton, race-condition

I have the following code to implement singleton

```
const singleton = Symbol();
const singletonEnforcer = Symbol()

class SingletonTest {

  constructor(enforcer) {
    if(enforcer != singletonEnforcer) throw "Cannot construct singleton";
  }

  static get instance() {
    if(!this[singleton]) {
      this[singleton] = new SingletonTest(singletonEnforcer);
    }
    return this[singleton];
  }
}

export default SingletonTest
```

And

```
import SingletonTest from 'singleton-test';
const instance = SingletonTest.instance;
```

I have a race condition problem , when `SingletonTest.instance` is executed at same time twice , I have two instance of `SingletonTest` , How can I solve issue?

Comment: Would it work if you just initiate private variable in the constructor and when you have instance of singleton just set it to true ?

Comment: @TomasRastenis No , It not works

Comment: I mean if its been to set to true return instance otherwise initiate

Comment: @TomasRastenis , Yes I know , I add a `_instance=false` private property and modify code to `if(!_instance){_instance=true;this[singleton] = new SingletonTest(singletonEnforcer);}`

Comment: @TomasRastenis when I have `_instance=false` , when `SingletonTest.instance` is executed at same time twice , once it return instance and once it return undefined